# How to host multiple website on Amazon EC2 single instance with SSL support?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl

I am beginner to Amazon Web Service. I want to host multiple websites on a single aws t2.micro server.  I found a solution below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/website1_folder"
ServerName yourdomain.com
ErrorLog "logs/yourdomain.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/yourdomain.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/website2_folder"
ServerName subdomain.yourdomain.com
ErrorLog "logs/yourdomain.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/yourdomain.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/website3_folder"
ServerName anotherdomain.com
ErrorLog "logs/yourdomain.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/yourdomain.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

However this solution works only for non ssl websites. How can I setup multiple websites on a single Amazon EC2 instance with ssl support? I prefer apache webserver as all of my website is going to be on php or static html. Is there any step by step guide from start to end configuration such as configuring instance, apache server, dns and ssl configuration? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a `t2.micro` with probably a `LAMP` stack, to avoid extra overhead using a CDN something like Cloudflare (https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204144518-SSL-FAQ)  could simplify this task.

Comment: @Foisal were you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple options

- wildcard certificate (such as *. mysite. com) allowimg you to use any subdomail, however usually these certificates cost someting and you are limited to a subdomain level
- you can request a certificate supporting a list of domains through "subject alternative name" https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm
- you can use SNI https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI  where a client sends the requested hostname during the ssl handshake amd server can use different certificates for different hostnames (most of current clients support SNI today, old browser versions or client frameworks may not support it)

I assume your best chances are with the SNI

Answer (score 0):

To get an SSL/TLS certificate from a third party, to use on your EC2 instance isn't cheap. I would normally use CloudFront to terminate the SSL/TLS connection, then let it communicate to your EC2 sites using http.

You can get a Cert for free in AWS Certificate Manager, and use of CloudFront for low volume sites costs pennies.

Use either a wildcard cert for all subdomains, list multiple domains in one cert, or separate certs, it's up to you.

As for a step by step guide, I've done this before on a previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51126705/6427978 though there may be some variation to support your usecase.