# How do I redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS in ELB without Apache and Nginx

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb

I am running python project on AWS and inplemented SSL with it. Everything is working perfectly.

Now I want to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS. It's very easy in apache/ngix but I am not using it. I have installed the SSl using AWS ELB.
So I need solution for above issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use AWS CloudFront for redirecting HTTP requests to HTTPS. It's not expensive and compliments ELB nicely, and brings other benefits too.

I wrote an answer to a similar question explaining how to set it up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51126705/6427978).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help.
I have created the cloudfront and it's working fine.
Also,I have added the CName in route53. But the domain is not redirected to https.

any suggestion?

Comment: The bit that makes that work is in the CloudFront distribution, select the "Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" option.

Comment: It's hard to say, I do it regularly and it just works. Make sure you have been through all of the steps in my guide. What happens when you do go to the HTTP site?

Comment: thanks for your precious time. I just want to reconfirm that is ot necessary to have certificate in us-east-1 ?
I am using the ELB with ACM.

Comment: For CloudFront you do need a cert in us-east-1 for TLS Termination. It's up to you if you then use http or https from CloudFront over the private AWS Network to your ELB, requiring another cert in the respective region.

Comment: Now I have setup all the instance in N.Virginia region. Even after that I am facing same issue. Now everything is proper and followed all instruction which were in your earlier answer. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to know what's going off without more information. Have a look at the AWS Documentation, see what you might be missing: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html

Comment: Let me explain all.

1. I have created instance under N.Virginia and setup my project on it.

2. Setup Elastic Load balancer for SSL and it workes well with the domain (https://gurunow.live) but  domin also works with http://gurunow.live.

3. So for redirection Implemented the CloudFront using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119542/unable-to-force-https-for-website-running-asp-net-on-elastic-beanstalk-aws-with/51126705#51126705
4. CloudFront works okay ie. d7v5f8kiwgm64.cloudfront.net
5. Added Cname in Route53
6. Now it should work